# Impala fails at creating partitioned table because of corrupted parquet file

Tags: dask, parquet, impala

I am saving a partitioned parquet file on a S3 bucket using Dask as such :

```py
dd.to_parquet(
    dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1),
    path='s3a://test/parquet',
    engine='fastparquet',
    partition_on='country',
    object_encoding='utf8',
    compression="gzip",
    write_index=False,
)
```

Parquet files are successfuly created ; here is the directory structure :
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHwLy.png)

I am successfuly creating an Impala table from this parquet :

```sql
create external table tmp.countries_france
like parquet 's3a://test/parquet/_metadata'
partitioned by (country string)
stored as parquet location 's3a://test/parquet/'
```

As well as adding a partition to this table :

```sql
alter table tmp.countries_france add partition (sheet='belgium')
```

However when I do a `select * from tmp.countries_france` I get the following error :

> File 's3a://test/parquet/sheet=france/part.0.parquet' is corrupt: metadata indicates a zero row count but there is at least one non-empty row group.

I guess the problem comes from Dask because when I create a non-partitioned parquet this works fine. I've tried setting `write_index=True` but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], size=1000),
                   'b': np.random.randint(0, 64000, size=1000),
                   'c': np.random.choice([True, False], size=1000)})
writer.write(tempdir, df, partition_on=['a', 'c'], file_scheme=scheme)
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
df.to_parquet('.', partition_on=['a', 'c'], engine='fastparquet')

pf = fastparquet.ParquetFile('_metadata')
pf.count  # 1000
len(pf.to_pandas())  # 1000
pf.row_groups[0].num_rows  # 171

pf = fastparquet.ParquetFile('a=a/c=False/part.0.parquet')
pf.count # 171
pf.row_groups[0].num_rows  # 171
```

Obviously, I cannot speak for what impala might be doing - but perhaps the "like" mechanism is expecting to find the data in the `_metadata` file?

Note that pandas can write to/from parquet without dask, with the same options.

Comment: The error is coming from here

https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/241adb116c3ab04917fe4100eff359dec9d395a3/be/src/exec/parquet/hdfs-parquet-scanner.cc#L1469

is the `num_rows` field at https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L1001 being correctly set?

Comment: It seems it is not, will log a bug on fastparquet.